# Drupal RSS feed links

Tags: drupal, rss, pathauto

I'm creating some feeds of news items and such. These items have URL aliases set for them. Is there a reason why the URL alias do not get used in the RSS feed?

I have a multi-language site which uses the path aliases to show correct navigation, and so when I get a 'node' link from the feed, it breaks everything.

**EDIT**

I'm creating the rss feed as using views
When I do a live preview in the view the correct link is shown. So the incorrect link comes somewhere after that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the feeds using Views? if not you should do it. It may be happening that the code that's returning the feed is printing the links to the nodes without using the l() function so aren't being translated to the corresponding alias.
Just in case, here it's a nice tutorial about how to do a feed with Views http://drupal.org/node/314097

Comment: Yes, I'm creating the feeds using views. And that was the exact tutorial that I followed to do it.